# Quickblox Login name cannot displayed in the cell row

Tags: iphone, chat, quickblox

I have using Quickblox framework for chatting purpose.login value set to each cell.row. but some values displaying "0" in cell.row. I have attached the below images and shows login as a number and name.
Below code the variable "testDict"  return null value sometime.

```
    QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [ChatService shared].dialogs[idx];
    NSDictionary *testDict=[ChatService shared].usersAsDictionary[@(chatDialog.recipientID)];
    QBUUser *recipient = [ChatService shared].usersAsDictionary[@(chatDialog.recipientID)];
    NSString *test=recipient.login == nil ? (recipient.fullName == nil ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)recipient.ID] : recipient.fullName) : recipient.login;

    NSLog(@"DialogList:%@",testDict);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the answer. just change the page:nil to page:[QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:20]

only get the 20 userlist display now

```
-(void)requestDialogsWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)())completionBlock{

self.getDialogsCompletionBlock = completionBlock;

[QBRequest dialogsWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *dialogObjects, NSSet *dialogsUsersIDs) {

    self.dialogs = dialogObjects.mutableCopy;


    [QBRequest usersWithIDs:[dialogsUsersIDs allObjects] page:nil
               successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *page, NSArray *users) {


               } errorBlock:nil];

} errorBlock:nil];
}
```